# Email attachments odoo 8 python

Tags: python, email, orm, odoo

I have problems creating email with attachments in odoo 8, I have created this function:

```
def send_desabastecimientos_report(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    if not context:
        context = {}
    # execution_date
    day = datetime.datetime.now()
    day = day. strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    #get attachment id        
    attachment_id=self.pool.get('ir.attachment').search(cr, uid, [('id',=, 806)] context=context)
    email_vals = {}
    # body message
    mesaage = "Reporte de desabastecimientos correspondiente al dia %s" % day
    # dict to send email
    email_vals.update({'subject':"Report",'email_to':'diego.mor13.dr@gmail.com', 'email_from': 'antonio.raskolnikov1311@gmail.com', 'body_html':mesaage.encode('utf-8'), 'attachments_ids': [(6, 0, attachment_id)] })
    # create and send email
    if email_vals:
                email_id=self.pool.get('mail.mail').create(cr, uid, email_vals, context=context)
                if email_id:
                   self.pool.get('mail.mail').send(cr, uid, email_id, context=context)
    return True
```

Setting up the debuger I get this dictionary to be sent:

```
dict: {'email_to':'diego.mor13.dr@gmail.com', 'email_from': 'antonio.raskolnikov1311@gmail.com', 'body_html': 'Reporte de desabastecimientos correspondiente al dia 2016-05-05', 'attachments_ids': [(6, 0, [806])], 'subject': 'Report'}
```

After creating the 'mail.mail' record, I get this console message:

```
2016-05-05 14:58:36,505 7444 WARNING mexyfeb18 openerp.models: mail.mail.create() with unknown fields: attachments_ids
```

And finally got the email sent without attachments.

This procedure works well when sending mail from Configuration->Email, actually is possible to attach files and attachment_ids field exists in mail.mail object.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace attachment**s**_ids with **attachment_ids**

Like : `'attachment_ids': [(6, 0, attachment_id)]`